# Cloning a website with website-scraper-puppeteer

Tags: cloning

I have an assessment to make the existing website look better with new UX design and just copied the whole page with npm website-scraper-puppeteer however the cloned site looks quite different from the original one. Could anyone shed some lights on how to fix this issue? Please refer to screen shots.

*Original Site
[image: Original site]

*Scraped site
[image: Scraped site]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks like the css file is missing or not loaded.
The npm site of website-scraper-puppeteer mentiones:
It starts Chromium in headless mode which just opens page and waits until page is loaded. It is far from ideal because probably you need to wait until some resource is loaded or click some button or log in. Currently this module doesn't support such functionality.

So maybe the css is loaded later.
You can have a look at the developer console of a browser you are opening the site with, it should tell you if some reference to a css file is missing. Then you can simply download the css file and add it.